# Rotating image round a fix point

Tags: iphone, ios, image-rotation

Firstly I am new to Objective C, any help will be most appreciated. I trying to write a Gauge app (which will eventually show the Angle of the phone). The issue I have is when I rotate the Needle image, it rotates to the correct angle, but not from the Anchor point - the image moves position. Even when I move, say from 0 dregs to 90 and back to 0, the image is does not end up back in its original position! The code I am using is below: .
(PS I am only currently only running the app on the simulator)

```
*** Rotate Invoked by ....
// Rotate Image
[self rotateImage:_imgNeedle duration: vAnimationDuration curve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear degrees:vValue];

-(void)rotateImage:(UIImageView *)image
       duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
          curve:(int)curve
        degrees:(CGFloat)degrees
{
  // Setup the animation
  [self setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(.44,.85) forView:image];
  // image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(d2r(degrees));

  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
  [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
  [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

  // The transform matrix
  CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(d2r(degrees));

  image.transform = transform;
  // Commit the changes
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}

// Set Anchor Point
-(void)setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint)anchorPoint forView:(UIView *)view
{
  CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * anchorPoint.x, view.bounds.size.height * anchorPoint.y);
  CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * view.layer.anchorPoint.x, view.bounds.size.height * view.layer.anchorPoint.y);

  newPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(newPoint, view.transform);
  oldPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(oldPoint, view.transform);

  CGPoint position = view.layer.position;

  position.x -= oldPoint.x;
  position.x += newPoint.x;

  position.y -= oldPoint.y;
  position.y += newPoint.y;

  view.layer.position = position;
  view.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the layer position, but when I change the anchorPoint, the frame changes, so I will adjust the frame.

```
-(void)setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint)anchorPoint forView:(UIView *)view
{
  CGPoint newPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * anchorPoint.x, view.bounds.size.height * anchorPoint.y);
  CGPoint oldPoint = CGPointMake(view.bounds.size.width * view.layer.anchorPoint.x, view.bounds.size.height * view.layer.anchorPoint.y);

  newPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(newPoint, view.transform);
  oldPoint = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(oldPoint, view.transform);
  /* 
  CGPoint position = view.layer.position;

  position.x -= oldPoint.x;
  position.x += newPoint.x;

  position.y -= oldPoint.y;
  position.y += newPoint.y;

  view.layer.position = position;
  */

  view.frame = CGRectOffset(view.frame, newPoint.x-oldPoint.x, newPoint.y-oldPoint.y);
  view.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
}
```

And also if you want to go back to the original position with multiple calling of rotateImage, I think you should only set the anchor point once before that. Since if you make two separate animation with the same rotateImage method, the anchor point will be recalculated with your current implementation.

```
-(void)rotateImage:(UIImageView *)image
       duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
          curve:(int)curve
        degrees:(CGFloat)degrees
{
  // Setup the animation
  // [self setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(.44,.85) forView:image];
  // image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(d2r(degrees));

  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
  [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
  [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

  // The transform matrix
  CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(d2r(degrees));

  image.transform = transform;
  // Commit the changes
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. I have made the changes, also noticed by sample rate was less than the animation duration. but while it is better, unfortunately it is still not quite right. In design on the Storyboard, the needle is in the Center of the of the Dial, When running it moves vertically up. Changing the angle I get some horizontal movement.

Comment: @user2413698 not sure what you need. Maybe you can update your question with more information. Or post another question if this answer has solved a particular issue you faced.

Comment: Have turnoff off auto-layout  - The needle now rotates correctly around the axis - Fixed!

Comment: @user2413698 ooh, cool :). Glad you managed to fix it. If my answer is correct, please accept it.